# Remove “deleted” flag from IMAP messages

Tags: thunderbird, exchange, imap

I use a **Microsoft Exchange 2010** email server and a **Mozilla Thunderbird** client. One day I selected a large part of my inbox and mistakenly pressed a keyboard shortcut which (I presume) **marked the messages for deletion**. The messages, of course, gets deleted. Now, the funny part begins: if I restore the deleted messages using "Recover deleted messages" feature in Outlook, the messages get back to the inbox BUT, as soon as I start my Thunderbird client, it deletes the messages again.

Now, as stated by this kb (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Deleting_messages_in_IMAP_accounts) the messages should have a "deleted" flag, so: **How can I clear that flag**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to Unix/Linux computer, you could use an utility like [`imapfilter`](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter). This is a useful utility you can configure with LUA config file. You can select your message using different kinds of filters, and then, do actions like moving messages, add/remove flags, etc.

You just have to install it and create a config file (IMAP account and rules). You can see an example for configuring accounts [there](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter/blob/master/samples/config.lua). Then, you can filter for messages marked as deleted and unmark them.

```
messagesMarkedAsDeleted = youraccount.INBOX:is_deleted()
messagesMarkedAsDeleted:unmark_deleted()
```

Finally, you can launch the program:

```
imapfilter -c /path/to/config.lua
```

I discovered this utility on [this blog](http://moiristo.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/sorting-imap-mail-with-imapfilter/) few weeks ago.

Hope this helped.